# Prevent same image & date looping when other categories dont have images

Tags: php

How can I set a default image to display when my other categories don't have any images? The problem I have at the moment is that it is showing the same image and date for the other categories which does not have any images yet. See the picture below for the current situation.

My code:

```
    <?php 
    include ('../../includes/connect.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM gallery_category";
    $res=mysql_query($query,$connection);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="../main.php">Back</a><br />
    <a href="upload.php">Upload more images</a> | <a href="add_cat.php">Add or 
    Delete  a Category</a>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ $id=$row['id']; ?>
    <h3><a href="plugin/index.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['name']; ?> (<?php $query1 = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($query1,$connection);echo mysql_num_rows($result);?>)
    </a></h3>

   <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id ORDER BY RAND() ");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){       
   $date =$row['date'];
   $name =$row['name'];
} ?>
    <a href="image2.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo           
   'upload/resized_'.$name; ?>" width="200" height="auto" /></a><br/>
<?php  echo 'Date: '.$date; 
   } 
   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The current situation:

[image: Screenshot showing the duplicated image and dates.]

Comment: Well, you can try setting an if statement in your img src, which says if file_exists() show image, if not, show placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check if image exists and act accordingly.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){    
   if($row['date'])   
   $date =$row['date'];
   else
   $date = $default_date; //date you need to display when no image is found
   if($row['name'])  
   $name =$row['name'];
   else
   $name =$default_name; //image name you need to display when no image is found
}
```